# SharePoint Online API(JSOM or REST) to get the site collection expiration date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

We are looking for client side SharePoint API(JSOM or REST) to get the site collection expiration date. We searched a lot and we are not able to find an api to get site collection expiration date.

Let us know if there is any api like that where we can get site collection expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

Hate to answer "you can't", but `ExpirationDate` really is not exposed in client side API (I double-checked with dotPeek).

There is some information about upgrade however, from that you might be able to calculate the expiration date indirectly. Namely, there's UpgradeReminderDate: [SP.Site.get_upgradeReminderDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246397(v=office.15).aspx). Of course, the reminder date is not very reliable, because it can be extended. Also, some other information about upgrade can be found in the UpgradeInfo property.

Also, I checked web services and sandbox, and unfortunately they don't expose anything about expiration date either.

The only crazy idea (definitely not recommended!) that crossed my mind is to web-scrape the expiration date from the SiteStatusBar control somehow :) But this control works only in the context of current web, so this might be very complicated technically...